Typing with TypeVar converts a type to an object
I am trying to implement a generator that will return a pair of a sequence element and a boolean value indicating whether the element is the last one.
from collections.abc import Generator, Iterable
from itertools import chain, tee
from typing import TypeVar

_T1 = TypeVar('_T1')
_MISSING = object()


def pairwise(iterable: Iterable[_T1]) -> Iterable[tuple[_T1, _T1]]:
    # See https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def annotated_last(sequence: Iterable[_T1]) -> Generator[tuple[_T1, bool], Any, None]:
    for current_item, next_item in pairwise(chain(sequence, [_MISSING])):
        is_last = next_item is _MISSING
        yield current_item, is_last  # <-- mypy error

However, mypy returns this error:
Incompatible types in "yield" (actual type "tuple[object, bool]", expected type "tuple[_T1, bool]")
Tell me how to correctly annotate types in these functions.
I am using Python version 3.9.19

I think _MISSING is not considered to be of type _T1, so the return of chain(sequence, [_MISSING]) is Iterable[Union[T1, object]]. What happens if you annotate _MISSING as _MISSING: _T1 = object()?

Your usage of chain is the cause.  Simply calling reveal_type(chain(sequence, sequence)) will show that  chain[_T1'-1], as they are the same type, but reveal_type(chain(sequence, [object()])) inside annotate_last(...) will show you that chaining the sequence with [object()] is the actual cause as it results in chain[builtins.object], opposed to the assertion in the title of this question: "Typing with TypeVar converts a type into an object".

@Aemyl Thanks for the comment. Your suggestion will not work because T1_ will be unbound in the global scope. And inside the function there will be an error Incompatible types in assignment

The definition of pairwise states that it takes an iterable of _T1 and returns an iterable of tuples of the same type, but you provide it with an iterable of _T1 and object, so it's correct to expect it will return an iterable of tuples of that union - even though we can see it would never actually do that at runtime. However, if you're doing this just to obtain a working annotated_last, I think there are simpler solutions. Is your question just about the error, or do you only need it resolved to get a correct and efficient annotated_last?

@Vladimir I didn't expect my suggestion to fix your problem, rather I hoped it could verify that the root of the mypy error is that _MISSING is not considered to be of type _T1. However, you are absolutely correct that _T1 in the global scope is not the same as _T1 in the annotated functions, I overlooked that.

@Grismar Yes, I would like to correct this mistake. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

This is because you created a chain iterator like so: chain(sequence, [_MISSING]), and the type inference has to infer the most generic type from these arguments, but _MISSING is object, so it has to be an iterator of object. Note, you can implement the function you want with the signature you want straightforwardly (albeit, less elegantly) doing something like:
from collections.abc import Iterator, Iterable
from typing import TypeVar

_T1 = TypeVar('_T1')


def annotated_last(sequence: Iterable[_T1]) -> Iterator[tuple[_T1, bool]]:
    it = iter(sequence)
    try:
        previous = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for current in it:
        yield previous, False
        previous = current
    yield previous, True


I was about to submit an answer with the same solution - although I nested the for inside the try section, and had the final yield in the else for the the for to make it immediately clear that is only intended to be executed after successful iteration through the full sequence - but it's a line longer and functionally identical, so a matter of style.
